# Can varying $p$ in the $p$-norm induced distanced change which pair of points are closer?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

i.e. For some $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, do there exist $p_{1}, p_{2}$ s.t.

$ 0 < \sum_{i=1}^{n} (|x_{i} - y_{i}|^{p_{1}} - |x_{i} - z_{i}|^{p_{1}})$
and

$ 0 \ge \sum_{i=1}^{n} (|x_{i} - y_{i}|^{p_{2}} - |x_{i} - z_{i}|^{p_{2}})$

Comment: Your "ie" doesn't seem quite right. The answer to the question in the title is of course - have you _looked_ for an example? ($p=1,2$, $x=(0,0)$, $y=(1,0)$, $(z=(2/3,2/3)$.) On the other hand, the most natural reading of the body of your post is that you're asking whether for every $x,y,z$ there exist $p_1,p_2$ such that etc., and the answer to _that_ is of course not, what if $y=z$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Well I would go with the title here - the only thing that changes the reading of the body of the post is the use of the word "fixed" rather than "some" and that is likely to just be a minor mistake.

Comment: Thank you, I meant to use "some", I will edit accordingly.

Comment: @Soke Thanks. Of course it was clear which reading was intended; thought I'd point out to the OP that that word "fixed" changes the meaning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x = (0, 0), y = (10, 0)$ and $z = (8, 9)$.

With $p = 2$ we have a standard Euclidean distance, and $z$ is further away from $x$ than $y$ (their distances are $8 \sqrt{2}$ and $10$, respectively).

With $p$ arbitrary large, however, we have the distance between $x$ and $y$ as $10$ while the distance between $z$ and $x$ as $9$.